# Save a file in Web API server file system

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API 2.2 with .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I want to save a file in a Server's folder (the folder is in the same server where Web API is running).

This is my code:

```
public class ProductionOrdersController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<PRODUCTION_ORDERS> m_PORepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<AGGREGATIONS> m_AggRepo;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> m_AggChRepo;

    public ProductionOrdersController(
        IGenericRepository<PRODUCTION_ORDERS> repository,
        IGenericRepository<AGGREGATIONS> aggRepo,
        IGenericRepository<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> aggChRepo)
    {
        m_PORepo = repository;
        m_AggRepo = aggRepo;
        m_AggChRepo = aggChRepo;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Close(long orderNumber)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        PRODUCTION_ORDERS po = m_PORepo.GetById(orderNumber);

        if (po != null)
        {
            // Generate XML
            ProductionOrderReport poReport =
                new ProductionOrderReport(m_PORepo, m_AggRepo, m_AggChRepo);

            XDocument doc = poReport.GenerateXMLReport(orderNumber);
            // Save XML.
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to do it. All that I found on Internet talk about how to upload files.

How can I do it?

Comment: Ironically, [XDocument.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the answer.

Comment: I will suggest you to use Azure Blob Storage instead.

Comment: @TIKSN For what *possible* reason are you suggesting that, here, now?

Comment: It is easy to use your file from any projects or API. I have a website which saves files and images in its directory. Now I have a problem with creating an Web API for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Save` method of `XDocument`

```
doc.Save("<path where you want to store>");
```

Make sure your application has permission access to the folder where you are trying to store file.

find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)